# General Question about Windows 7(Kiosk) Group Policy Lock down of Silverlight Out of Browser

Tags: silverlight, windows-7, administrator, kiosk, group-policy

I'm hoping to lock down, a Windows 7 laptop into more or less a kiosk type mode.  Basically login to Windows 7, automatically open up a silverlight out of browser application.  It should also prevent the removal of the silverlight app.

I can think of a few dirty ways to do this off the top of my head, I'm just hoping for a more holistic approach along the Microsoft-way of doing things.  Maybe add them to a domain, inherit some Group Policies from an OU that would restrict the above.  But I'm not sure if that's how it should be or could be done.

Any recommendations or suggested reading from the admins in the crowd?  I'm basically just looking for a good spot to start digging.

Thank you.